# JQuery: cant hide section tag in an p tag

Tags: jquery, html

So i am joking around with jquery (imma nub). now i found something interesting: why i cant hide the text in the section tag. it works fine when its like `<section><p>blabla text text</p></section>`
I didnt find anything on google. I would like to fix it with the jquery execution code!
Problem code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("p  section").hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>


<h2>This is a heading</h2>

<p>
  <section>This is a paragraph.</section>
</p>


<p>This is another paragraph.</p>

<button>Click me to hide paragraphs</button>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `section` shouldn't be a child of `p` tag...

Comment: Might have to see with the fact that a section` within a paragraph is not semantic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Section cannot be nested inside any other element.Section stands on its own

**From HTML5 Doctor
The section element represents a generic document or application section…The section element is not a generic container element. When an element is needed only for styling purposes or as a convenience for scripting, authors are encouraged to use the div element instead. A general rule is that the section element is appropriate only if the element’s contents would be listed explicitly in the document’s outline.
section is a blob of content that you could store as an individual record in a database. It generally looks like this (and note that the heading goes inside the section element, not immediately before it):**

change your snippet as the following should work

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("section").hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>


<h2>This is a heading</h2>


  <section><p>This is a paragraph.</p></section>



<p>This is another paragraph.</p>

<button>Click me to hide paragraphs</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `<section>` **cannot** reside within a `<p>` tag. Think about it, a 'section' shouldn't reside within a 'paragraph'. What you may be looking for is `<span>`. This way, you can style **part** of a paragraph:

```
$("p > span").hide();

<p>
  <span>This is a paragraph.</span>
</p>
```

I've created a working fiddle demonstrating this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/vn4got2y/).

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

The HTML5 spec tells us that the `<p>` element's content model is phrasing content.

so only the following tags can be inside the `<p>` tag. Not a jquery bug ;)

> a (if it contains only phrasing content), abbr area (if it is a
>   descendant of a map element) audio b bdi bdo br button canvas cite
>   code command datalist del (if it contains only phrasing content) dfn
>   em embed i iframe img input ins (if it contains only phrasing content)
>   kbd keygen label map (if it contains only phrasing content) mark math
>   meter noscript object output progress q ruby s samp script select
>   small span strong sub sup svg textarea time u var video wbr text